# Getting error while implementing oAuth2.0 in C# Console Self Hosted web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, self-host-webapi

I am getting **localhost(portnumber)://signin-google?state=blahblahblah...** once google signing in process completed.

Below is the main entry point from where API runs.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var app = WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:8090"))
            {
                Process.Start("http://localhost:8090/api");
                Console.WriteLine("Close this window to stop this server");
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
        }
```

Below is my startup.cs class code

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var cookieOpts = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login"),
                CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest
            };
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOpts);

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(cookieOpts.AuthenticationType);
            var googleOpts = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "XXXXXXXXX",
                ClientSecret = "XXXXXXXXX"
            };
            app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOpts);

            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerTypeResolver), new ControllerResolver());
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
```

The controller from where google sign in challage page is executed is

```
 [RoutePrefix("account"), AllowAnonymous]
    public class AccountController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet, Route("login")]
        public IHttpActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            var authProps = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = returnUrl
            };
            Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(authProps, "Google");
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }

        [HttpGet, Route("logoff")]
        public IHttpActionResult Logout()
        {
            Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

The controller for which I am using google authorisation is

```
 [RoutePrefix("api"), Authorize]
    public class DefaultController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet, Route("")]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok("Hello, world!");
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine 
 1. When application starts it checks for google login
 2. If not then it will redirect to google sign in page
 3. after sign in into google it is redirecting back to localhost(portnumber)://signin-google?state=blahblahblah..

I guess it should redirect to actual api - in my case it should have http://localhost:portnumer:/api

Below is the trace capture file for quick reference -  [Trace-log-is-here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thir4.png)

Thank you in advance..:)

Source Code - https://github.com/BDChaudhari90/OAuthGoogleSelfHost

Comment: Can you share your code? All I'm seeing is links to `localhost` which, for obvious reasons, we can't see your project. This doesn't help us help you because we don't know what you're working with.

Comment: Here the code is 
https://github.com/BDChaudhari90/OAuthGoogleSelfHost

Comment: please edit your question and include a minimum verifiable example of you issue.  Remember that your client id and secret are to be kept secure you should not include them in open source projects

Comment: Yes that I know - Thank you 
I already reset my clientId and client secret :)

Comment: @DaImTo Can you please check it and do let me know if you have any urgent solution for this as I stuck in this issue from last 2 days

Comment: There should be an exception (that's why you get an "internal server error"). Can you post the exception details?

Comment: How to get that error - this is returned from google I guess - see the trace log at here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/thir4.png

Comment: No, it's from your localhost. Google redirects back to your localhost and there is the error.

Comment: I will be happy to look but you need to edit your question and add enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DaImTo Code is available at - https://github.com/BDChaudhari90/OAuthGoogleSelfHost

Comment: Welcome to stack we ask that you post [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking questions not post a link to another site

Comment: @DaImTo - Thank you for message - I just have updated my question with actual code. Could you please look into this if you can help to resolve this.